# Plugin to manually retry a parametrized build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have the following scenario:

- A parameterized Jenkins project that is triggered by another project.
- The build fails because of an external resources such as disk space.

What I want is this, if the build fails, then I can fix the external problem, and simply click a button to repeat the build again with the same parameters.

Does this plugin exists? I haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**Rebuild**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin) plugin is what you want